# boxes stay empty after UPDATE sql query in ms-access

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update, datediff

I created the following query in MS ACCESS:

```
"UPDATE dbo_PricingFutures
SET dbo_PricingFutures.ttm = 
DateDiff('m',dbo_PricingFutures.PricingDate,DateSerial(dbo_PricingFutures.PricingYear,dbo_PricingFutures.PricingMonth,14));"
```

When I run the query, which should calculate the difference between dates.  It says it is going to update the records:

[image: updating rows]

However the fields in the column stay empty. I don't understand why?

Comment: I think you are seeing the SELECT of the Query which will always be empty. To actually see if the Query has made an effect you need to check the table which you are updating.

Comment: I checked the table and it is still empty

Comment: Curios. When you click `Yes` to the above message box, does it come up with warning or error message?

Comment: I am stupid. I replaced by a vba code and it showed me an error: the column pricing date was empty! Then, I took the data from an old back up and I put it in the empty column and it works :) . Sorry for my stupidity.

Comment: No problem ! Glad you have it sorted ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a mistake, the column pricingdate was empty.
I ran the following vba code:

```
Sub ttm()
    Dim db As Database, rs As DAO.Recordset, strsql As String
    Dim startdate As Date, maturity As Date, maturity_month As Double
    Dim maturity_year As Double

    Set db = CurrentDb()
    strsql = "SELECT * FROM dbo_PricingFutures ORDER BY PricingDate;"
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strsql, dbOpenDynaset)
    rs.MoveFirst
    While (Not rs.EOF())
        rs.Edit
        startdate = rs.Fields("PricingDate")
        maturity_month = rs.Fields("PricingMonth")
        maturity_year = rs.Fields("PricingYear")
        maturity = DateSerial(maturity_year, maturity_month, 14)
        rs.Fields("ttm") = DateDiff("d", startdate, maturity)
        rs.Update
rs.MoveNext
    Wend

    rs.Close
    db.Close
End Sub
```

Then I got an error on the following line:

```
startdate = rs.Fields("PricingDate")
```

It showed that the column PricingDate was empty.
Then, I took data from an old back up, copy/pasting in the column PricingDate and it worked perfectly.

The SQL code was running without showing error.